# how can i assign ObjectListView Checkbox Value

Tags: c#, winforms, objectlistview

I am using `ObjectListView`, and I am dealing with Checkboxes in it. In the documentation of the `ObjectListView` it is mentioned that i can use this code to set the checkbox value:

```
foreach (OLVListItem olvi in objectListView1.SelectedItems) 
   olvi.Checked = !olvi.Checked;
```

But i cant use the `OLVListItem`. What namespace should i add to the project? And what is the difference between setting the checkbox value by using this way and setting putter delegate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have `using BrightIdeasSoftware;` up there ;)

Whenever you run into this, click on the object type, in this case OLVListItem, and press Ctrl+. and you'll get a little menu with the option to add the appropriate using!! See, Visual studio knows what namespace everything you reference but wants you to specify!

Answer (score 0):

Where did you take this code from? Was it by any chance from http://code.google.com/p/jingxian-mailer ?

If you have taken this from there, then the OLVListItem is a class from that project that inherits from `ListViewItem`. Take a look at http://code.google.com/p/jingxian-mailer/source/browse/trunk/jingxian.ui.controls/FastListView/OLVListItem.cs, I hope this helps.

Comment: i saw this code in http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html#recipe-checkbox under                                                                 10. How do I use checkboxes in my ObjectListView?

Comment: iam using another class of list view i dont think this will help